# MySQL database and Web service for Android App

Tags: android, mysql

While using MyPHP admin, I edit records in mySQL database that then is updated into my Android application.

If I paste data into one of my table fields, I often get "NULL" displaying in my app. If I paste the web service URL into a browser I still get the NULL value for that particular field.

After further experimenting, I noticed that editing some characters, that tend to be non-standard, the NULL is replaced with my data. This characters seem to be apostrophes, dashes, and brackets...etc.

Is there some way to do a mass conversion so all my data will paste into my table without editing special characters?

I have tried pasting into Notepad and other editors with the same result.

I then tried various means to ensure my tables were using utf8 character set. This yielded no data to my app. (the Browser method still worked). I don't remember adding anything to my app that set the charset.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to judge without sample data, url, etc. But I would say, given that this data will be displayed on a mobile device, that you probably would need to paste your data into something like TextWrangler, or NotePad++ and you will have to do a regular expression find and replace on all of the special characters. When you're finished, you would have to reimport into your database.

Another solution is to filter out the special characters right on the server. You could use the PHP str_replace function to filter out special characters as well.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am already doing a manual find/replace. It's not much fun. And, creating a filter might be a huge job because I can not predict which of the many many many non-standard may be used in the text.